# pass variable from javascript function to controller method in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm new in CodeIgniter. I am making a project in which I make a javascript function in view an in this I define a variable .. it looks like this

```
var $rowCount=0;
function invest() {
  $rowCount=$('#ulinvestment').find('.rowInvestment').length;
}
```

my controller function contains

```
function input(parameter //i want to pass $rowcount value here ){
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->helper('html');
$this->load->model('mod_user');
$this->mod_user->insertdata();
 }
```

I want to access the variable `$rowCount` in controller function, how can I do that?

Comment: it's better if you do javascript stuffs in 'VIEW' file.

Comment: @Charlie: this javascript is on view . .

Comment: you can not access javascript variable in php. Simple reason is Javascript is client side whereas PHP is on server.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi : i actually want to call controller function(for example input(parameter)) in my javascript code on view

Comment: @Jay than impletment ajax.

Comment: $.post('codeigniter/controller/input',{ param1: "param2", param2: "param2" } function(data) { $('.result').html(data);});

Comment: in form action i pass url of controller methode,can i delete it . . @SureshKamrushi

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27224/discussion-between-jay-and-suresh-kamrushi)

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I understand you, You are trying to pass a variable from javascript to CodeIgniter's controller function, right?

If that's your case(hopefully it is), then you can use AJAX, or craft an anchor link.

First of all, you're going to use the [URI class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html), specifically the `segment()` function.

Let's assume this is your controller:

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller
{
    function input(){
    $parameter = $this->uri->segment(3);//assuming this function is accessable through MyController/input

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->model('mod_user');
    $this->mod_user->insertdata();
    }
}
```

Now with javascript you can either craft an anchor tag, or use AJAX:

**Method 1:** By crafting an anchor tag:

```
<a href="" id="anchortag">Click me to send some data to MyController/input</a>


<script>

var $rowCount=0;
function invest() {
  $rowCount=$('#ulinvestment').find('.rowInvestment').length;
}
$('#anchortag').prop('href', "localhost/index.php/MyController/input/"+$rowCount);
</script>
```

**Method 2:** By using AJAX:

```
var $rowCount=0;
function invest() {
  $rowCount=$('#ulinvestment').find('.rowInvestment').length;
}
//Send AJAX get request(you can send post requests too)
$.get('localhost/index.php/MyController/input/'+$rowCount);
```