# CodeIgniter - How to parse value from javascript to models ?? Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

This is my first time using CodeIgniter and I wanna get the value from javascript and call the model. Here's the codes:

**VIEW**

```
function fnFormatDetails ( oTable, nTr )
          {
              var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );  
              var agen = aData[2];  
              var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border=" 0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
              sOut += '<h5>Agen Induk: '+aData[2]+'</h5>';
              sOut += '<tr><th>Nama Pangkalan:</th><th>Nomor Kontrak</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>';  
            <?php     
                foreach ($pangkas as $joss) { 
             ?>
              sOut += '<tr><td><?php echo $joss->nama_pangkalan ?></td><td><?php echo 'agen' ?></td><td>20</td></tr>';
            <?php 
                } ?>
              sOut += '<tr><td></td><td><b>Total Tabung</b></td><td>80</td></tr>';                        


              return sOut;
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function index(){
    $data['module']="agen";
    $data['view_file']="daftaragen";  
    $this->load->model('agen_model');  
    $this->load->model('pangkalan/pangkalanmodel');   
    $data['allagen'] = $this->agen_model->semuaagen(); 
    $data['pangkas'] = $this->pangkalanmodel->get_pangkalan_by_id($id);       

    $this->load->view('template/templatehome',$data);  
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public function get_pangkalan_by_id($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('t_pangkalan'); 
    $this->db->where('agen',$id);
    $qry = $this->db->get();

    return $qry->result();
}
```

**THE GOAL**
I want the sample data (in the pict) SAMPLE 1,2 shown in first row. and the SAMPLE 3 shown in second row. Any ideas?
[This is the goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efq7T.png)

Comment: Check this answer of StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/15754674/3081659

Comment: thanks for advice, but the problem is I only have a button (+) and (-) for expand or collapse  the table. And the button made in javascript.